# Are the connections in the pictures below an attempt at stealing power for another apartment

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need help indentifying if the connections here are stealing power from one apt. for use in another.suspect

[image: suspect1]

[image]

Comment: There's no way to tell what is going on in these photos, without knowing where each wire goes/comes from.

Comment: "Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by incompetence."

Comment: Easy way to tell, turn the breakers off for a week and see if anyone complains. Since we don't have telepresence capabilities to trace out where this wiring goes, you'll need to get an electrician out before the shoddy wiring burns something up.

Comment: You should tell us where you are located as wiring standards vary wildly.

Comment: This looks like a fire waiting to happen. If your not an electrician maybe you should actually pay to have your own electricity turned on. Bigger problems await you.

Answer (score 5):

**Call an electrician immediately** that panel doesn't look safe.

It looks like someone with some electrical knowledge attempted to do some work, that is definitely not to code and should be fixed properly immediately.

Comment: could you elaborate further on what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Well for starters you've got 3 pieces of electrical tape on one 1 wire - *probably* got stripped (compromised) when the wire was forced through.  There is no grommet on the wire coming in from the right, some wire is exposed connecting to the breaker. This would NEVER pass inspection, done by someone who knew enough to be dangerous. - Just because it works, doesn't mean it's safe.

Comment: Looks like they have #8 connected to the 40A breaker, then #12 or #14 taking power from there down to the 25A breakers. Looks like maybe an attempt to burn down the apartment, not to steal power.

Comment: Keep in mind, this DOES NOT look like a North American installation. This may be high end workmanship where the OP lives.